# How do I split lines up in latex by a certain character?

Tags: unix

I have a bunch of lines similar to:

Jasmine, Kellyn, Shelly; Applebees

Sarah; Walmart

Helen, Max, Sam; Dell

Many of these names repeat. I need to figure out the top 10 used names. Ive been trying to use cut -d"," restaurants.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n 10

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this isn't pretty, but at least it works.

```
 cat restaurants.txt | sed 's/;.*//' |  tr "," "\n" | tr " " "\n" | grep -v '^$' |  sort | uniq -c | sort -r
```

`2 Sam

   2 Max

   1 Shelly

   1 Sarah

   1 Kellyn

   1 Jasmine

   1 Helen`

Explanation:
`sed 's/;.*//'` removes all text after the semicolons like(; Applebees)

`tr "," "\n"` uniq only works per line, so replace commas with new lines

`tr " " "\n"` cleans up any extra spaces by giving them their own line (optional)

`grep -v '^$'` Deletes all empty lines

`sort` sorts

`uniq -c` counts duplicates

`sort -f` organizes in descending order